# What happens to existing data if AWS CloudHSM is zeroized?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

This is probably a Noob question, but I was unable to find an overt answer.

**Question:** If using CloudHSM to provide keys, what happens to your existing encrypted data if the CloudHSM is zeroized?

If CloudHSM has wiped out its bank of keys and I don't have any CloudHSM backups, does this mean my data encrypted with CloudHSM-managed keys is now unable to be decrypted? If not, why not?

**Context:** I've read that CloudHSM will zeroize if a user with Crypto Officer (CO) credentials fails to login after 5 consecutive failed attempts.  Zeroization means CloudHSM will wipe out its current key data and reinitialize, and the keys it managed cannot be retrieved except from backups.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. This question might be a better fit on [Super User](https://superuser.com). I suspect the answer is: of course the data can no longer be decrypted since the decryption keys are deleted and there's no backup.